# least square means for dataset with missing data

Tags: r, least-squares

I am writing for some help in R.

I am doing a simple RCBD analysis using the following script to
compare genotypes (Name)
for the trait "X".

```
library(stats)
data_1=read.table(file="test.txt", head=TRUE)
result_X =aov(X~Block+Name, data=data_1)
sink("result_X.txt")
summary(result_X)
sink()
```

My data has missing data ("NA"). So, after calculating the LSD,
I would like to compare
the genotypes in descending order. I do not think the averages
are good since some
'blocks' for some 'names' are missing.

So, the question is, what is the script to print out the 'least
square means', which I
think are the best to compare with LSD than simple averages.
Thank you for your help,

Oswald

Comment: For a start, see [this discussion on R-help][1], you can also try the [`lsmeans` package][2] available on R-forge. 


  [1]: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02/archive/95809.html

  [2]: https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/lsmeans/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function `na.omit`, which can filter out rows of data which contain `NA`.